# Is it correct to work with the width and height parameters after making the setMeasuredDimension call?

Tags: android, onmeasure

I created a custom view in which I want to draw a series of squares, the side of the square depends on the dimensions that are assigned to the view, so in my method `onMeasure()` after checking mode and size, I call setMeasuredDimension (width, height).
Now it is correct to perform operations after setMeasuredDimension like

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    /*******/
    setMeasuredDimension(width,height);
    squareSize = width / rows;
}
```

Comment: When the only thing needed is a views final width and height, we usually use onSizeChanged method for that.

Comment: Even views width and height params are available also in onMeasure and will do the job, that method is overriden mostly for manipulating the actual measuring process of the view